# I need to use both AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMetadataOutput

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm writing an app that needs to look at the raw video (custom edge detection etc) **and** use the meta data barcode reader.

even though the AVCaptureSession has an `addOutput:` method instead of `setOutput:` method, that's exactly what it's doing - first one in wins.

if I add AVCaptureVideoDataOutput as output first - it's delegate gets called.
if I add AVCaptureMetadataOutput as output first -  it's delegate gets called.

Has anyone figured out a way around this? 
short of removing the other one every other frame?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add both `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`.

```
NSError *error = nil;

self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];

// Select a video device, make an input
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice;
AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
// Find the front facing camera
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
    if ([device position] == desiredPosition) {
        captureDevice = device;
        break;
    }
}

AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

if (!error) {

    [self.captureSession beginConfiguration];

    // add the input to the session
    if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
        [self.captureSession addInput:deviceInput];
    }

    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *metadataOutput = [AVCaptureMetadataOutput new];
    if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:metadataOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:metadataOutput];

        self.metaDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("MetaDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        [metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:self.metaDataOutputQueue];
        [metadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
    }

    self.videoDataOutput = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];
    if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.videoDataOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:self.videoDataOutput];

        NSDictionary *rgbOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
        [self.videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:rgbOutputSettings];
        [self.videoDataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];

        self.videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        [self.videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue];

        [[self.videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:YES];
    }

    [self.captureSession commitConfiguration];
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}
```